# WP Multisite Users Not Linking

Tags: database, users

Hi everyone… I’m trying to make a multi site (same site but different languages) and I need it to be available to all users, but when I make an account, it can only log in but has no access to any other content (ex. user dashboard)…

We checked the database and there is only one users field (I thought it might have made a different one).

How can I fix this?

P.S. I chose this option because the UI needs to be in the user defined language, and with translators plugins it translates the added content too, which needs to remain in the original language.

Comment: Questions about WordPress are out of scope here at Super User.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/409892/edit) to clarify what you're asking. When you say "I need it to be available to all users", do you mean that all users in the Multisite network need to be able to view content from all sites? Do they all need to be able to *edit* content in a given site or all sites?